# how can detect incoming and outgoing email from android device?

Tags: android

I  create android apps for detecting incoming and outgoing mail from android device.
But i am not aware that this concept may work. Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. Sorry!

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/202628/whos_calling_android_app_promises_true_caller_id.html

Answer (score 0):

As Vineet said, this doesn't work. The only way this works is when the user a mail client that   broadcasts out an Intent which you can receive.(The only one I know of is K9Mail)

What you could do is read the email's inbox yourself and react to a new mail there and then but also broadcast a ACTION_SYNC intent so (hopefully) the native mail app will sync and read the new mail?

Comment: Actually i want to do that Suppose we send mail from android device . Now we want to detect the outgoing mail through my application i.e collect all information like volume of text, sending time ,destination address and more.